# HighStock/HighCharts DataGrouping

Tags: charts, highcharts

Hi there I am using highstock. Im displaying a large amount of data so I am using data grouping. I want to limit the number of point displayed to 60-70, so i need to group my data in 60-70 groups. How can i do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the [datagrouping](http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#plotOptions.series.dataGrouping.units), you can define a units, but not "maximum points" of groups.